# Json parsing with dotted path in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing, pypi

Is there any python library (PyPI) available from which I can parse json with :

```
1.  dot separated path
2.  order independant in case of array
```

Data :

```
  "attr1": [
    {
      "attr2": "val2"
    },
    {
      "attr3": {
        "attr4": "val4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here, I am having path such as `'attr1.attr3.attr4'`. From which I need to get value `'val4'`.
With the use of dotty dict library, I must provide position in case of array: `'attr1.1.attr3.attr4'`. But position can vary. It may possible that `'attr3'` comes first in `'attr1'`.

So, is there any library available which can provide

```
1.  'val4' when I pass 'attr1.attr3.attr4' path  (Not 'attr1.1.attr3.attr4')
2.  'val2' when I pass 'attr1.attr2' (Not 'attr1.0.attr2')
```

Comment: You need just flatten json.

Comment: try jsonpath-ng: https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/

Answer (score 1):

- you can recursively check for whether its a `list` or `dict`. And generate key depending upon whether its a `dict` or `list`.
- This is hacky solution and I dont know whether this will work for your case. But here is my best try.

```py
d = {
    "attr1": [
    {
      "attr2": "val2"
    },
    {
      "attr3": {
        "attr4": "val4"
      }
    }
  ]
}

l = dict()
def foo(x, z):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for val in x:
            foo(val, z)
    elif isinstance(x, dict):
        for k,v in x.items():
            foo(v, z+"."+k)
    else:
        l[z[1:]] = x


foo(d, "")

print(l['attr1.attr2'])
print(l['attr1.attr3.attr4'])
```

- output

> val2
>   val4

Comment: Hi Poojan, appreciate your quick assistance. However, Is there any PyPI library available for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a function which would parse the string that you provide it to with the dictionary object. Hope it helps you.

The advantage here is, you never parse the whole dictionary and just get the values that are required. for example if you wanted to access 4 keys separated by `.` then complexity will be 4. It will always return the result in o(n) where n is the number of keys.

```
def get_value(dotted_str, dict_obj):
    names = dotted_str.split('.')
    current_level = dict_obj
    for index, name in enumerate(names):
        if index:
            if isinstance(current_level, list):
                current_level = current_level[int(name)]
            else:
                current_level = current_level[name]
    return current_level


a_dict = {"a": {"this": 100, "is": 500, "nested": [{"first": 0}, {"second": ["I", "am", "list"]}]}, "b": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
get_value("a_dict.a.nested.1.second", a_dict)
```

Output of above code is:

```
['I', 'am', 'list']
```

Comment: Hi, is there anything which uses 'a_dict.a.nested.second' as path instead of 'a_dict.a.nested.1.second' and provide correct output?

Comment: I didn't get it, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I do not want to bind path with ordinal position in array. Here you provide path as "a_dict.a.nested.1.second" in which you are getting 2nd element in nested array and then find 'second' in that. In short, position can vary in array.

Comment: You can have any array that you want and this will work, I used the name 'second' on that position for the sake of readability